# How to have prod and dev Firebase projects with the same Auth configurations?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Firebase Auth as an authentication service for my Node.js back-end app (with firebase-admin).

As far as I understand, there is no way to have only one project that can be used for both development and production environments.

So, I created two separate projects (one for dev, one for prod). My question is: how should I make the configuration of the two projects consistent? For example, I want both projects to only allow authentication with only Email and Facebook. How should one do this automatically? Is there a way to do it with firebase-tools? I don't want to manually modify each project as this will, no doubt, lead to mistakes.

I guess that if it is not possible, I will consider creating my own authentication system.

Thank you!

Comment: I think that there is currently no way to set automatically it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this automatically.  In the future, something like this would end up as part of the collection of [project management APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest).  Feel free to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature) for what you'd like to be able to do with your project programmatically.